# jQuery variable$ what does the $sign mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I am studying jQuery I encounter this code.

```
var allImages$ = $('img');
```

Can anyone tell me what does the $ sign mean in allImages$? does it refers to a function or it is part of the variable name? What if I use

```
var allImages = $('img');
```

Any difference?

Thanks,

Comment: It is just a variable name, user might have added a `$` to make it explicit that it holds a jquery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no operational difference between your two lines of code.

The `$` is just a programming convention that some people use to indicate that the variable contains a jQuery object.  It's a hint so that a developer using this variable later on in the function will now whether the object is a DOM object or a jQuery object and will be sure to use the appropriate methods and it makes the code a little more descriptive.

The use of naming conventions like this is a personal preference as a coding style.

The `$` is just a normal character that is allowed in variable names so it means nothing special to the javascript engine.

Here's [an article](http://www.moreonfew.com/naming-conventions-in-javascript/) on a number of javascript naming conventions (not specific to jQuery).

---

For some serious variable naming conventions see the [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) that was popular at Microsoft for programming in "C" (I was not a fan of this one).

Comment: Hi, jfriend00 and all friends who answered, Thanks a lot for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

No difference.  `$` is allowed in variable names.  It's usage is only a convention.

But a common convention when using `jQuery` is to use `$` to note that the variable represent a jQuery object, in your case a jQuery wrapped `<img>` node.